# How to remove https redirect of checkout page of localhost

Tags: wordpress, checkout

I search but checkout tab not show in woocommerce setting. how to remove https redirect of checkout page in localhost.

[image]

Comment: Check advance settings, uncheck "Force secure checkout" option if it checked.

Answer (score 2):

[You can find these option at woocommerce > Advanced > Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WYj5.png)

Comment: Ohh sorry for late reply.but glad to hear that it works.If my suggestion was helpful for you please +1 for the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Woocommerce Booster" Plugin. All settings on one place, also you can edit everything inside woocemmerce with one plugin. There is also option for /links and force https. It save me a lot of time when I need to test something or to change settings often, and you can edit plugin different ways if you want to play with it.